# parse json data consists of null values

Tags: json, ruby-1.9.3

```
Trying data['external_address_package'] getting error like :

**syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
{"data":{"external_address_package":{"...**
```

> {"data":{"external_address_package":{"created_at":"2017-03-21T05:18:44Z","description":null,"error_messages"
>   :null,"external_id":null,"geolocating_time":null,"id":2631,"importing_time":null,"log_file":null,"name"
>   :"new_week_13","norm_address_package_id":null,"num_addresses":null,"num_new_addresses":null,"priority"
>   :null,"status":"loading_addresses","updated_at":"2017-03-21T05:19:06Z","human_status":"Loading addresses"
>   }},"importing":"  new_week_13 \n  03/21/2017 05:18 am\n  Loading addresses Loading addresses(1/12)"}

```
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Provide your complete JSON

Comment: @SanchayKumar Thanks for your quick response. The above mentioned data is the complete json response. I didn't modify the json response. Now I have to deal with this json response further.